# Url Rewriting working except for one link

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, url-routing, yii-url-manager

This is the url manager code inside *config/main.php*

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'urlSuffix'=>'.html',
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    ),
),
```

Locally it works perfectly. It's working in our server too except for urls with controller name as careersVacancies.

This is the error I'm obtaining

> Error 404 Unable to resolve the request `"careersVacancies/careers"`.
>
> Error 404 Unable to resolve the request `"careersVacancies/index"`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you verify the case of your filename carrersVacancies.php ?

Comment: this was working perfectly before applying url manager in yii..So i dont think there is any problem with the casing